# 2d array as indexed property of java bean

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, javabeans

Is there a way to use multidimensional arrays as the indexed properties in Java Beans? I mean something like

```
public class BeanDemo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int[][] property;

    public BeanDemo() {

    }

    public int[][] getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(int[][] property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public int getProperty(int i, int j) {
        return property[j][i];
    }

    public void setProperty(int i, int j, int val) {
        property[j][i] = val;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code should work, but not purely Java Beans specs.

Each property should be a single item.  so the last `set` is not really Java Beanish.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You can use single-dimensional array or collection of Java Beans rather than a multidimensional array.